# Clear Gmail mail and password cache in firefox

Tags: firefox

Even if I clear the Firefox data like this:
[image]
When I go to Gmail to log in, it offers me my mail already typed in the text field for mail address, and if I choose it, I can see that my password is already typed in too.

How can I delete/disable this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Preferences` -> `Privacy & Security`, under `Forms and Passwords` there is a `Saved Logins...` button, which will allow you to see and selectively delete what has been saved.

[image: Firefox privacy settings]

If you never want any log-ins to be saved, clear the `Remember logins and passwords for web sites` tick-box; or if you want to exclude certain specific sites use the `Exceptions...` button.

The screen-shot was taken from FF58.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.4, but it will be in similar locations in other revisions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is in the form history and not the cache, you can usually delete saved form entries by hovering over it and pressing shift delete.
https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1056299

Comment: It works. Also, it's `Delete`, not `Shift+Delete` on Linux.